# Prevent click multiple times until .toggle() with effect is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using JQuery UI to toggle the div with effect `.toggle('blind', 250)`.
I have tackled the .stop() method but it was not my goal in toggling the div, because when I want to toggle the div `#clContainer` even clicking multiple times the other div `#ccConatiner` can only be toggled next when it is done...

Here's my Code

```js
$(function(){
  $("#clContainer").on('click', function(){
    $("#ccContainer").toggle('blind', 350);
  });
});
```

```css
#ccContainer,
#clContainer{
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

#ccContainer{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 </head>
 <div>
  <div id="clContainer">
   Click me
  </div>
  <div id="ccContainer"></div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a flag each time your animation starts, and clear it when it finishes. and on each click check for the flag to see if there is an ongoing animation and only animate again if there isn't any ongoing animation.

you can use `.promise().done()` to set a callback function that will run as soon as all animations on your cube finish, and in this callback clear the **animation_ongoing** flag:

```js
var animation_ongoing=0;
$(function() {
  $("#clContainer").on('click', function() {
    if(!animation_ongoing){
      animation_ongoing=1;
      $("#ccContainer").toggle('blind', 350).promise().done(function(){
          animation_ongoing=0;  
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#ccContainer,
#clContainer {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
#ccContainer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<div>
  <div id="clContainer">
    Click me
  </div>
  <div id="ccContainer"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do... thanks a lot :)